# How to show TabbarController from a button click segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue, tabbarcontroller

I have a tabbarcontroller and it has 3 tab like Home,Cam and Profile. It is working perfectly. Also i want to show profile view from a different profile button. So if i clicked this button it shows profile view but tabbar is disappearing but i dont want this. 
Actually system like an instagram clone. In instagram if you click a username then you can see his/her profile view and tabbar not disappearing. Also you can go profile view with profile tab. This not working in my project.

I can easily going to the profile view from TabBarVC. There is no problem in here. But in table view controller. I have custom cell in table view and there is a button in this cell. I wanna go to profile view when i click this button. It works but when i clicked this button, tabbar in the profile view is disappearing.

```
func profileSelected(index : Int) {
    selectedUser = objects[index].valueForKey("user") as PFUser       
    performSegueWithIdentifier("profile", sender: self)
}


 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.destinationViewController is ProfileVC {
        var profileVC = segue.destinationViewController as ProfileVC
        profileVC.user = selectedUser
    }
}
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide coding examples. Your description is not enough for anyone to be able to assist you.
If you don't want to share any of your code:
Check out public projects on GitHub or look at CocoaControls to see if they have what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Dominic. I will share some codes and screenshots as soon as possible.